# php versions are shown differently in WHM and server

Tags: php, centos, cpanel, whm

In server, it shows 7.0 php like below from either cPanel

[image]

or `cat /etc/apache2/conf.d/php.version` in server

[image]

However in `php --version`, it shows php5.6.

[image]

How can I upgrade my php to 7.0? Thanks.

Comment: it is possible to have multiple installs, especially on shared servers where multiple versions are required. When you run PHP -v or PHP --version you are getting the current CLI version of PHP, this does not necessarily reflect the PHP version on each domain.

Comment: @MHewison So if I want to update the php version in my server, I have to update it manually instead of just update the version in cPanel/WHM?

Comment: You are "installing" new versions of PHP through Cpanel? I have no idea how that works. Would guess though that it is something of a walled garden. If you want to change the PHP version your system would use on the CLI I would use YUM. Are you clear on the distinction of CLI vs CGI/FCGI?

Comment: Might also do a `which php` maybe cpanel is providing the php-cli, not messing with what is on your path, you would then just need to be explicit as to which php you want to use.

Comment: @ficuscr Definitely not sure about the distinction of CLI vs CGI/FCGI LOL. But if you said you would use yum to update the PHP, I think it would be a good start for me to take a look on google. Thanks:)

Comment: @ficuscr ```which php``` shows ```/opt/rh/rh-php56/root/usr/bin/php```

Comment: When I updated the "System PHP Version" from WHM, it reflected the the `php --version`, how do you execute `php --version` ? wish SSH ?

Comment: @Accountant ```ssh -i /my/key user@domain.com```

Comment: @PakHoCheung would check `/opt/rh/rh-php*/root/usr/bin/php` might find the other versions. Google up some other SO questions about multiple PHP versions and diff. between the PHP "associated" with a web server and the CLI one. You'll find a lot on the topic and only take a few minutes to get up to speed.

Comment: @PakHoCheung check [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php/1190483) also

Comment: @ficuscr Thanks for the guide:)

Comment: @AccountantمThanks for the guide:)

Answer (score 0):

If you change PHP version from cpanel account it will be applied and your website will use the new version.

`php -v` command shows the default version of PHP for your system but if you want to check PHP version for your cpanel account only you have to modify your `~/.bashrc` file:

`alias php="/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php"`

and then:

`source ~/.bashrc`

Now you'll find the output some thing like:

```
php -v
PHP 7.0.33 (cli) (built: xxxxxx) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```